# When do you call the super method in viewWillAppear, viewDidDisappear, etc...?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

In [UIViewController's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller), Apple suggests calling the super at some point in the implementation of viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, viewWillDisappear, viewDidDisappear, etc... For example, the discussion on viewDidDisappear is:

> You can override this method to perform additional tasks associated
>   with dismissing or hiding the view. If you override this method, you
>   must **call super at some point in your implementation**.

My question is does it matter **when** the super method is called and, if so, what is the correct time to call it? Should super be called as the first line of the method, the last line, or somewhere in the middle depending on your particular needs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `viewDidAppear` call `super` first so that your calls will override.

In `viewWillDisappear` it seems to be a toss up, I have researched that extensively and could not find a conclusive answer and it seems to be 50/50. I have decided to call `super` last in my code in the same manner we call `super` last in `dealloc`.

Comment: How did you come up with these rules?

Comment: In viewDidAppear it seems obvious that the subclass dawning should on top of the super class' so super is called first.  As for viewWillDisappear I have seen no good reason one way or the other so I went with my gut--until proven wrong. :-)  If you have a view or seen a good rationale please post!

Answer (score 2):

I generally will call these first within my implementation. In most cases it shouldn't matter though.

Answer (score 2):

For `UIViewController`'s view life cycle methods, I'd say that there is no silver bullet rule for determining when to call `super`, what you should be aware of is that sometimes you *must* call it regardless of whether it should be at the begging or at the end of the method. For instance, citing from [`viewDidDisappear(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621477-viewdiddisappear):

> You can override this method to perform additional tasks associated
>   with dismissing or hiding the view. If you override this method, you
>   **must** call super at some point in your implementation.

**However**, as a general practice we usually call the `super` method at the beginning in methods that related to initialization, setup or configurations; On the other hand, we usually call the `super` method at the end in methods related to deinitialization or similar methods.

Here is an example of `XCTestCase` class's invocation methods:

```
override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    // do the setups, such as creating the mock objects...
}

override func tearDown() {
    // make your objects no be nil for the next test...
    super.tearDown()
}
```

So (as another example), when it comes to the `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidDisappear` methods:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    // my code...
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // my code
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
}
```