# When to call super in UIViewController life cycle methods?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, lifecycle

I've seen implementations of the UIViewController life cycle methods, where the super method was called at the beginning, like this:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do stuff after super call.
}
```

But I have also seen this:

```swift
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // Do stuff before super call.
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
}
```

When should `super` be called at the end?

Comment: ViewDidDisappear cleans off the stuff in your VC so later you will not have a chance to do it anymore. After that, it's over :)

Comment: You could check my answer on the duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60436107/5501940